# :first-child not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first `h1` inside a `div` with a class called `detail_container`. It works if `h1` is the first element within this `div`, but if it comes after this `ul` it won't work.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.detail_container h1:first-child
{
color:blue;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="detail_container">
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>First H1</h1>
    <h1>Second H1</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was under the impression that the CSS I have will select the first `h1` no matter where it is in this `div`. How can I make it work?

Comment: Whatever CSS can't do, JavaScript can.

Comment: This is something you can do with CSS3 though :)

Answer (score 283, accepted):

The `h1:first-child` selector means

> Select the first child of its parent
>   if and only if it's an `h1` element.

The `:first-child` of the container here is the `ul`, and as such cannot satisfy `h1:first-child`.

There is CSS3's `:first-of-type` for your case:

```
.detail_container h1:first-of-type
{
    color: blue;
}
```

But with browser compatibility woes and whatnot, you're better off giving the first `h1` a class, then targeting that class:

```
.detail_container h1.first
{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I understand now, though I think they should have implemented both versions when they created the standard.

Comment: Not working in IE9 release. It says h1:unknown in developer tool

Comment: [Compatibility list](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t34) of `:first-of-type` selector.

Comment: [Newer compatibility list](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) of `:first-of-type`. Old link is incorrect.

Comment: In my view, the term `:first-child` is not clear to understand, because you define the item as CSS selector, say `h1`, and then you subsequently think "take the first child" of all in the chosen DOM level. I used it wrong so many times... We have to get used to the `:first-of-type` selector and think of the *first child* of its type.

Comment: You could also use this: ```.detail_container > h1:first-child``` and it will work

Answer (score 23):

`:first-child` selects the first `h1` **if and only if** it is the first child of its parent element.  In your example, the `ul` is the first child of the `div`.

The name of the pseudo-class is somewhat misleading, but it's explained pretty clearly [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) in the spec.

jQuery's `:first` selector gives you what you're looking for.  You can do this:

`$('.detail_container h1:first').css("color", "blue");`

Comment: Your right it is misleading, I mainly got confused because I have used jQuery to do this before.

Comment: Where CSS fails, Javascript Works.. !! Finally achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 10):

you can also use

```
.detail_container h1:nth-of-type(1)
```

By changing the number 1 by any other number you can select any other h1 item.

Answer (score 9):

For that particular case you can use:

```
.detail_container > ul + h1{ 
    color: blue; 
}
```

But if you need that same selector on many cases, you should have a class for those, like BoltClock said.

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues. Here the ref http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your `h1` tags in another `div` and then the first one would be the `first-child`. That `div` doesn't even need styles. It's just a way to segregate those children.

```
<div class="h1-holder">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
</div>
```