# How to style for first-child of a certain type of element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For example, I have HTML like :

```
<div class='page'>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>6</a>
</div>
```

How can I style for first child a

I used like this : `.page a:first-child {color:red}`

but it doesn't run.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use **[`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)** instead of **[`first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)**

```
.page a:first-of-type{
    color:red;
}
```

> The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.

Taken from [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type). You can find more details & examples [here.](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)

Explanation : [:first-child not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505686/first-child-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 12):

As Pranav c said, you can use
`.page a:first-of-type { ... }`  or  `.page a:nth-of-type(1) { ... }` but neither of them will work in **IE8**

So if we can assume that the `<span>` is always going to be there, then

```
.page span+a { ... }
```

will ensure that only the first a after the span will be styled and this is as good as you can get cross-browser right now.

Example: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCyLw/)