# Get an element's nth-child number in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I am making a function for my site where I set a data attribute which contains the nth-child number of that element.

My HTML markup:

```
<html>
<body>
    <section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is one</section>
    <section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is two</section>
    <section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is three</section>
    <section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is four</section>
    <section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is five</section>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript so far:

```
var selector = document.getElementsByClassName('hardware');
for(var i = 0; i <= selector.length; i++) {
    var index = selector[i] //get the nth-child number here
    selector[i].dataset.number = index;
}
```

How can I get the nth-child number of an element with pure JavaScript (not jQuery), is this even possible in JavaScript?

Comment: that is pure javascript no?

Comment: @bitoiu Yes it is, but how can I get the nth-child number?

Comment: If it's possible with jQuery, it's also possible without. Remember, jQuery is just a set of JS functions. It makes things easier, it doesn't add extra functionality.

Comment: Why to set "`[object HTMLElement]`" as `data-number` value? (`selector[i].dataset.number = index;`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "number", do you mean 1, 2, etc or "one", "two", etc?

If 1, 2, etc, then the number is simply i+1...

If "one", "two", etc, then you need to get the text inside the element, then probably use a Regexp to parse it and get the value you want.

Comment: Then `i+1` is what you want.

Comment: @Sake Salverda: This only "works fine" when the entire set of elements returned by your `getElementsByClassName()` is contained under the same parent and there are no other child elements that could interfere with `:nth-child()`. But if you can always rely on that assumption, then `i+1` will indeed suffice.

Answer (score 7):

Check out this previous answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913927/get-child-node-index).

It uses

```
var i = 0;
while( (child = child.previousSibling) != null ) 
  i++;
//at the end i will contain the index.
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply incrementing the index linearly will only work if *all* the elements matching that class name are the only element children of the same parent, with no other elements that could interfere with `:nth-child()`, as shown exactly in the given markup. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505686/first-child-not-working-as-expected/4505716#4505716) for an explanation on how other elements might interfere. Also review the [Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) on `:nth-child()`.

One way to achieve this that is more foolproof is to loop through the child nodes of each element's parent node, incrementing a counter for each child node that is an element node (since `:nth-child()` only counts element nodes):

```
var selector = document.getElementsByClassName('hardware');

for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
    var element = selector[i];
    var child = element.parentNode.firstChild;
    var index = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            index++;
        }

        if (child === element || !child.nextSibling) {
            break;
        }

        child = child.nextSibling;
    }

    element.dataset.number = index;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/5dh5r/2)

Note that this will apply the correct index *regardless of where the given element is in the DOM*:

- If a particular `section.hardware` element is the first and only child of a different `section`, it will be assigned the correct index of 1.
- If a `.hardware` element is the second child of its parent, even if it is the only one with that class (i.e. it follows some other element *without* the class), it will be assigned the correct index of 2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer the questions with the following assumptions:

- Your `hardware` classed elements are all siblings
- You are interested in nth child not nth child + 1
- They can be mixed with other elements:

```html
<body>
    <section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is zero</section>
    <section class="software"></section>
    <section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is two</section>
</body>
```

(I'm making these assumptions, because this is the problem I'm facing, thought it could be useful)

So the main difference is that instead of querying the elements that belong to a given class, I'm going to get the (direct) children of the `body`, and filter them.

```
Array.from(document.body.children)
  .map((element, index) => ({element, index}))
  .filter(({element}) => element.classList.contains('hardware'))
```

The resulting array will look like this:

```
[
  {element: section.hardware, index: 0}
  {element: section.hardware, index: 2}
]
```

Comment: "You are interested in nth child not nth child + 1" But nth-child is 1-indexed...

Answer (score 1):

```
[].slice.call(elem.parentElement.childNodes).indexOf(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Erik's answer is a hint to how easy the solution is in modern-day browsers, with one bug.
`childNodes` includes text nodes, whitespace nodes, comment nodes, and will not translate into CSS compatible `nth-child`'s. Here is a version that matches the CSS standard:

```
Array.from(elem.parentNode.children).indexOf(elem)+1
```

Keep in mind that CSS indexes are not zero-based but JS indexes are, hence adding 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text at the spaces at get the last *word* from each split-array:

```
var hards = document.getElementsByClassName('hardware');
for (var i=0; i < hards.length; i++) {
    var hardText = hards[i].innerText || hard[i].textContent;
    var hardList = hardText.split(' ');
    var hardLast = hardList[hardList.length - 1];
    alert(hardLast);
}
```

I am using || here because Firefox does not support `innerText`, while IE does not support `textContent`.

If the elements only contain text then `innerHTML` can be used instead of `innerText/textContent`.