# Check if current element is even or odd

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

Is there an easy way to check whether the current element in a nodeList is an even/odd child of its parent.

For example, if have a list of links.

```
<ul>
 <li>Odd</li>
 <li>Even</li>
 <li>Odd</li>
 <li>Even</li>
 <li>Odd</li>
</ul>
```

And I iterate over a nodeList like this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   var link = links[i];
   var parent = link.parentNode;

   if (// this is an even link) {
      console.log("even");
   }
   else {
      console.log("odd");
   }
}
```

How would I determine if the current link is even or odd?

I was thinking of selecting a new nodeList of all the parent's odd `li` elements using `li:nth-child(odd)` on the parent and then checking whether the current node is in that nodeList. Although I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

How can I check whether the current node is even/odd in relation to its parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is similar to [Get an element's nth-child number in pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436442/get-an-elements-nth-child-number-in-pure-javascript)

> How can I check whether the current node is even/odd in relation to its parent?

The problem with simply incrementing `i` on every iteration, as all the other answers are doing, is that this calculation makes no relation to the parent node whatsoever. If you notice, none of the existing answers make use of `link.parentNode` at all!

Since the calculation isn't aware of the context of the parent node, it basically assumes there is exactly one `ul` element and all `li` elements are children of that one `ul` in order to work correctly. The moment you have nested `ul` elements or even just multiple `ul` elements in the same document, it will break.

Note that the problem is *not* with the `%` line. In fact, that is exactly how you determine if an integer is even or odd. The problem is that the index isn't being calculated in relation to the parent node.

For example, if I modify your list to include a nested `ul` with exactly one `li`:

```
<ul>
 <li>Odd
  <ul>
   <li>Odd</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Even</li>
 <li>Odd</li>
 <li>Even</li>
 <li>Odd</li>
</ul>
```

The output will be [all wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/76VCH) once it counts the inner `li` (the second line):

```
[12:07:25.505] odd
[12:07:25.505] even
[12:07:25.505] odd
[12:07:25.505] even
[12:07:25.506] odd
[12:07:25.506] even
```

I wrote a script in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436442/get-an-elements-nth-child-number-in-pure-javascript/24437151#24437151) to the similar question I linked to above. Here's a quote:

> One way to achieve this that is more foolproof is to loop through the child nodes of each element's parent node, incrementing a counter for each child node that is an element node (since `:nth-child()` only counts element nodes):

And here's the script, adapted for your use case:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   var link = links[i];
   var parent = link.parentNode;
   var child = parent.firstChild;
   var index = 0;

   while (true) {
      if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
         index++;
      }

      if (child === link || !child.nextSibling) {
         break;
      }

      child = child.nextSibling;
   }

   if (index % 2 == 0) {
      console.log("even");
   }
   else {
      console.log("odd");
   }
}
```

Now the output will be [correct](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/76VCH/1):

```
[12:35:22.273] odd
[12:35:22.273] odd
[12:35:22.273] even
[12:35:22.273] odd
[12:35:22.273] even
[12:35:22.273] odd
```

Again, the second line represents the inner `li`, which in the modified HTML is the first (and therefore odd) child of its parent `ul`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your answer BoltClock, this is exactly what I was looking for and what I was trying to acheive! Really appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether `i+1` is even or odd

```
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   var link = links[i];
   var parent = link.parentNode;

   if ((i+1)%2 == 0) {
      console.log("even");
   }
   else {
      console.log("odd");
   }
}
```

Comment: would that work if I had nested links? (eg. UL of LI's inside a LI inside a UL)?

Comment: Or … simply omit the `+1` and use `!=`.

Comment: @Kay why would it matter?

Comment: That's what I was saying, I need to determine based on the parent, not based on the loop iteration. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3143218: Yes, I'm writing an answer as we speak.

Answer (score -1):

Use [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators):

```
if ((i+1)%2==0) {
      console.log("even");
   }
   else {
      console.log("odd");
   }
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but see my answer, as well as my comment on Victor Castillo Torres's answer.