# first-child was not workded in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

The below was the html and css code, and I want to ask the question: why the first-child does not work? Who can tell me,I will appreciate for your answer.

```css
.footerLinks {
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
.show{
  display: inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  color:#eee;
  padding:4px 14px;
  border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-left:1px solid red;
}
.footerLinks li a:hover{
  color: red;
  border-top:1px solid #fff;  
}
.footerLinks .show:first-of-type{
  border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul class="footerLinks">
    <li class="show-first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't see a left border at the first element?

Comment: Are you compiling in regular css or in [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)?

Comment: @David I am sorry, I compiling in less, but I choose it into css, it still does not work yet.

Comment: @FengLi In this case, it won't work in CSS like this, use `.element:before {}` and `.element:hover{}` instead

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:first-child not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505686/first-child-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: @snkv  I want to set the '.show' selector first element css style by ":first-child", not others

Comment: @FengLi, use :first-of-type instead.

Comment: @GabrielCheung I change into first-of-type, but it does not work yet

Comment: @C0dekid why it won't work?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.footerLinks {
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
.show{
  display: inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  color:#eee;
  padding:4px 14px;
  border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-left:1px solid red;
}
.footerLinks li:first-child{
 border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul class="footerLinks">
    <li class="show first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have a condition, every line has different style, but contain two line has the same style, and the second line's margin-bottom was none, so this solution does not suit me. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it should be `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child` since you have a different class as the `first-child` of the `ul`.

Example:

```
&:first-of-type {
      border-left:none;
  }
```

Or you can move the first `li` element out of the `ul` like below.

```css
.footerLinks {
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
.show{
  display: inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  color:#eee;
  padding:4px 14px;
  border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-left:1px solid red;
  &:hover {
      color:#fff;
      border-top:1px solid #fff;
  }
  
}
.show:first-child {
   border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
    <div class="show-first"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
  <ul class="footerLinks">
    <li class="show"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The reason is that, if you use `:first-child` selector with class, it behaves more like `li:first-child.class-name`. So if your first-child does not have a correct class name, it fails.

Comment: It still does not work yet after I changed the "first-of-type" from "first-child"

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax.
&:hover {} is not valid css code. You can use & in SASS or LESS or other preproccesor, but not pure CSS.
You probably don't need that "show-first" class and do it with :first-child.

Working code:

```css
.footerLinks {
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
.show{
  display: inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  display:inline;
  color:#eee;
  padding:4px 14px;
  border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-left:1px solid red;
}
.show:hover {
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
}
.show:hover a {
    color:#fff;
}
.show:first-child {
    border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul class="footerLinks">
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I runed in less environment, post it into the snippet, forget to change it into css, I already changed the question。Thanks for you help me to find the error。

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is the class of your first `li` item. It is set to `.show-first` , when all the others are set to only `.show`. You must change your class to `.show.first` so that `.first` can be a modulator-class and not a whole new class name as `.show-first`.

The `first-child` selector works fine, it just needs to see that first `.show` class, thats all.

```css
.footerLinks {
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
.show{
  display: inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  color:#eee;
  padding:4px 14px;
  border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-left:1px solid red;
}
.footerLinks li:hover{
  color: red;
  border-top:1px solid #fff;  
}
.footerLinks .show:first-child {
  border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul class="footerLinks">
    <li class="show first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li class="show"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```