# css first child not wokring

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```css
.resources .resource:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #D9B310;
}

.resources .resource {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D9B310;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="resources">
  <h2 class="text-center">Ресурси</h1>

    <div class="resource">
      <h4>Минерали <span class="resource-quantity">3700</span></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="resource">
      <h4>Газ <span class="resource-quantity">500</span></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

the selector without the first-child works fine. But the first-child selector it's not wrking in my case. Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:first-child not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505686/first-child-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:first-of-type` because it's second child of it's parent.

```css
.resources .resource:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #D9B310;
}

.resources .resource {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D9B310;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="resources">
  <h2 class="text-center">Ресурси</h2>

    <div class="resource">
      <h4>Минерали <span class="resource-quantity">3700</span></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="resource">
      <h4>Газ <span class="resource-quantity">500</span></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because that the `.resource` element that you want to stylize is the **second** child of it's parent, the first child is the `h1` tag (careful, your **heading** tags were not properly closed).

You may be mistaken `:first-child` with `:first-of-type`.

- `:first-child` only selects the `.resource` elements that are the first child within their parent container.
- `:first-of-type` selects the `.resource` elements that are the first element **matching the given selector** (`.resource`) within their parent container, but not necessarily on the first-child position.

You can either use `:nth-child(2)` or `:first-of-type`, as in your case the element is the second child.

```css
.resources .resource:nth-child(2){
  border-top: 1px solid #D9B310;
}

.resources .resource {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D9B310;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="resources">
  <h1 class="text-center">Ресурси</h1>

    <div class="resource">
      <h3>Минерали <span class="resource-quantity">3700</span></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="resource">
      <h3>Газ <span class="resource-quantity">500</span></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.resources .resource:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #D9B310;
}

.resources .resource {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D9B310;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="resources">
  <h2 class="text-center">Ресурси</h2>

    <div class="resource">
      <h4>Минерали <span class="resource-quantity">3700</span></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="resource">
      <h4>Газ <span class="resource-quantity">500</span></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```